# How to stop video in MPMoviePlayer programmatically

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

i want to stop a video after certain time and during that time i want to show my own contents, it is just like ads play during television show and it resumes after the ad has run.

Comment: how you did you start your video?

Comment: i am playing a video in a MPMoviePlayer normally.